# SSRS : Programmatically generating a report

Tags: .net, reporting-services

In a .net application, how can I generate a report and save it as some type of a file (preferably a pdf)? 
Is it possible? Also, is it possible to send a couple of parameters that the report needs?

I am able to add a web reference to `ReportingServices2010.asmx` and query the report for properties. (It returns just the name of report as a property). But not sure how to proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is fairly simple. Using the `ReportExecutionService.Render` method you can render the report however you want. We've used this to run reports and attach them to emails automatically.

The MSDN site [has some code to get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx).