# how to automatically save fresh SSRS report on a hard drive daily

Tags: sql, reporting-services, subscription

I have subscribed SSRS report that is executed on a daily basis. But I also want the copy of that report automatically saved in a folder on a local machine with slightly changed name of the report.
So one copy goes to the user, the other copy goes to the hard drive.
Is that possible to achieve that?

Comment: Can you set up the target directory as a file share?  If so, you can set up a second subscription to be delivered to a Windows File Share instead of email.  When you do so, there are different options for what to do with the file which includes incrementing the file name.

Comment: Awesome!Thank you very much!

Comment: But also is any chance I can dynamically to add date to the report?
For example "Clearance Report 08312016"  
something like that
Thank you

Comment: You can add **@timestamp** to the **File Name** field of a Windows File Share subscription. Unfortunately it will include the time and isn't flexible or otherwise formattable (did I just make up a word?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the **Enterprise Edition**, you can use a **data-driven subscription** that uses a query to populate the report name.

You would have a query as the source with a field for the report name:

```
SELECT 'Report Name ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS REPORT_NAME, ...
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I have a standard edition. But that would be the best way.

Comment: Using SSIS it is possible to set up a job to render the report and save it to disk see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429387/ssrs-programatically-generating-a-report.  Also see - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15555/Generating-PDF-reports-programmatically-using-SQL.  This is something l did for a previous company.  A data driven sub is by far the simplest solution though.